# videoView doesn't show anything

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

I need help with a `VideoView` problem with in Android. I've tried everything and even look up on stackoverflow questions, but no one has this exact problem.

**Problem:**
The View supposed to show the picked video from gallery (this action is triggered by a button), but even though there's no error in the log and the uri is not null nothing is shown in the view. All of this is in a `Fragment` inside `ViewPager`. (If looking at the code below, the `Log.d("FragCamera", "I_REQUEST_VIDEO_PICK mediaUri : " + mediaUri);` is run and mediaUri is not `null`. So I don't know what else could be the problem.)

Btw, I'm using Marshmallow real device to test this with usb debugging feature on and the app is set to JellyBean and above. And I don't think it's a permission problem as in the same page I have code using the same permission and it works fine.

**Can anyone tell me why I can't get it to work?**

===================================

This is my code. It's been stripped down to just the essential code to trigger this problem. `checkPermission()` is a method to check and request permission on runtime, and it works fine as the other code using this function and same permission works ok.

**fragment_camera_action.xml**

```
<VideoView
   android:id="@+id/preview_up_vid"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

**`fragment.java`**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera_action, container, false);

    uploadedVid = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.preview_up_vid);
    btn_getvid = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_getvid);

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(ctx);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(uploadedVid);
    uploadedVid.setMediaController(mediaController);

    btn_getvid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("FragCamera", "btn_getvid on click.");

            String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

            if (checkMPermission(ctx, permissions, P_REQUEST_PICK_VIDEO)) {
                pickVideo();
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}

private void pickVideo() {
    Log.d("FragCamera", "pickVideo()");
    Intent pickPictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    pickPictureIntent.setType("video/*");
    this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickPictureIntent, "Select Video"), I_REQUEST_VIDEO_PICK);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d("FragCamera", "onActivityResult()");

    Uri mediaUri;

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case I_REQUEST_VIDEO_PICK:
                uploadedVid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d("FragCamera", "pickVideo() RESULT_OK");

                if (data != null) {
                    mediaUri = data.getData();
                    Log.d("FragCamera", "I_REQUEST_VIDEO_PICK mediaUri : " + mediaUri);

                    uploadedVid.setVideoURI(mediaUri);
                    uploadedVid.setZOrderOnTop(true);
                    uploadedVid.start();

                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your uri?

Comment: @VivekMishra ok, I'm able to give the correct (real) value of the mediaUri from the log. It's : `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A27222`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few test and tweak, I finally got `VideoView` to work. A few things that I found to make it works (at least, for my case) are:

**1. It needs to be inside a `FrameLayout`.**

I've tried nesting it inside a `RelativeLayout/LinearLayout` with layout_height set to `match_parent` or `wrap_content`, but it doesn't work. With `FrameLayout` either value for `layout_height` doesn't seem to matter.

**2. `VideoView` `layout_height` must be set to `match_parent`**

I've checked the official doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#inhattrs), but in the `inherited XML` section, there's no mention it inherited `layout_height` or `layout_width`, or even if the value must be `match_parent`, but I can't get it to work any other way. And although it does state it inherited `minHeight`, setting `wrap_content` with `minHeight` still doesn't render the view.

======

I don't know if this helps, but I also do a `Clean Project` before this works, so it might be playing a part to this. Altough afterwards, I did various test to trigger my problem back, and it results to the points I wrote above.

And while I read in SO that a lot of people use RelativeLayout or even LinearLayout to hold this view and it works with them, I just can't seem to make it work in mine during my test.

Hope this helps other people who face this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I to faced similar issue.  **uploadedVid.setZOrderOnTop(true);**   is the culprit. I would suggest you to use  *compile 'com.sprylab.android.texturevideoview:texturevideoview:1.1.1'*  library instead of default VideoView

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm not able to test your solution atm, but originally, I code without `uploadedVid.setZOrderOnTop(true);`. It's something I found suggested as an answer a lot on other questions here in SO, so I added it, but sadly it doesn't help me. I'll be sure to test out your suggestion once I'm able :)

Comment: so I'm able to try out your suggestion and it works ok :). The video is just a second or two slower than when I'm using VideoView, but as long as it doesn't get out-of-sync (video to audio) it won't be obvious unless  someone comparing it side by side :). Thanks, but I think I'll stay with VideoView now that I managed to get it to work  :)

Comment: Actually VideoView extends SurfaceView . So.if we you use  <b>setZOrderOnTop(true)</b>  you can't add have any Views like (Play , Pause and ProgressBar ..etc That's the reason I suggested to use 3rd party library. It's up to you @aya

Comment: I thought it wasn't that strict, at least you can have other views, but the VideoView will be forever on top of those other view... and since at the time I wanted to test out why it doesn't even render the view in mine, I added it the attribute. Thanks for the info though! :)